# Google Sheets: Copying a cell with multiple font styles (colors) to another cell maintaining style

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste, richtext

How can I copy a cell with different font colors to another cell? Basically want to perform a standard copy-paste maintaining styles of the copied cell ... below are examples of source cells:

[image]

The format is important as it gives more info based on the different color codes.

Comment: Tried `Range.copyTo()`?

Comment: @TheMaster I think the OP wants to copy the text format, not the cell format.

Comment: @Marios All formats are copied.

Answer (score 1):

[Range.copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range)) emulates a normal copy paste done manually by a user. It preserves all formatting including rich text.

```
function copyAsCopiedByUser(){
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  sh.getRange("A1").copyTo(sh.getRange("B2"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have just tried something and it has worked. Much easier than I thought in the end.

```
function copyWithFormat() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var sourceRange = sheet.getRange("B1");
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange("C1");
  var sourceText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue();
  sourceText = sourceRange.getValue().toString();
  var sourceFormat = sourceRange.getRichTextValue();
  targetRange.setValue(sourceText);
  targetRange.setRichTextValue(sourceFormat);
  
}
```